# Implementing Interceptor in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, authentication

Looking at this `AuthInterceptor` from this helpful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255203/angularjs-clientside-routing-and-token-authentication-with-webapi), how are the `request` and `response` key's used in the returned JSON object?

Also, what's the meaning of `return config || $q.when(config)`? I understand that the second part is returned if `config` is `null` or `undefined`, but what does `$q.when(config`) mean in this code?

```
myApp.factory('AuthInterceptor', function ($window, $q) {
    return {
        'request': function(config) {
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            if ($window.sessionStorage.getItem('token')) {
                config.headers.Authorization = $window.sessionStorage.getItem('token');
            }
            return config || $q.when(config);
        },
        'response': function(response) {
            if(response.status === 401) {
                $location('/login');
            }
            return response || $q.when(response);
        }
    };
});
```

I typed out the above linked answer. It worked for me, but I don't understand how it's used.

Answer (score 1):

`request` and `response` are simple used as intermediaries. In other words, the `request` function is run prior to a request (after requesting), and the `response` function is run prior to handling a request result.

---

`$q.when()` ensures that the return value is able to be handled as a promise. Essentially it wraps the value in a promise, so that functions like `returnedValue.then()` work.

See: [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q)

Kevin asked why you would want to use `$q.when()`. This is to ensure that any outside function that consumes this one receives a promise, if it is expecting one. For example, imagine the situation where you call a function expecting a promise:

```
someThirdPartyFunc(someArg).then(function(result){
    // do somethign with result
});
```

If you ran this and `someThirdPartyFunc` returned a simple value (say 100), then this would obviously fail. If the implementor wrapped the return value in `$q.when(100)`, then the function call above would be valid, and `result` would contain the value 100.

Comment: why would you want to handle a return variable as a promise?

Comment: Updated answer for you.

Comment: so let's say that my regular, non-intercepting code executes: `$http.post("foo/bar.com")`, expecting a `promise` back. This HTTP POST returns an object: `{count: 100}`. The above `response` property of my `AuthInterceptor` would return the object as `response` is truthy. Wouldn't this implementation then break the expected promise result of the caller of the `$http.post(...)`? Or perhaps it's up to the implementor to decide whether to return `response` or `response wrapped in a promise`?

Comment: This is why I don't see the purpose of returning a promise. Normally (i.e. if `config` is defined) the function will return an object (not a promise), but if `config` is not defined then it will return a promise (wrapped around the undefined `config`). It doesn't make sense and indeed it seems like breaking your own implementation (but again I might be missing something).

Answer (score 1):

When registering an `$http` interceptor, you should essentially pass an object with the following (optional) keys: request, requestError, response, responseError.
For more info on when each interceptor function is called, take a look at **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916989/when-do-functions-request-requesterror-response-responseerror-get-invoked-whe/23917941#23917941)**.

`$q.when()` turns any JS object into a promise (that resolved immediatelly with the passed in object as each resolved value). But, frankly (although I've seen it a lot) I don't understand why one would need to return `config || $q.when(config)`, instead of just `config`.

Comment: could you please say a bit more: `I don't understand why one would need to return config || $q.when(config), instead of just config.`? I'd like to know what you're thinking, please.

Comment: Actually, there nothing moe to say other than what I said in my comment to Matt Way's answer (which is essentially what you said in your comment).